# Custom Border Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget, border

[image]

How to make such a widget so that the Row widget is in the middle in the header, and behind the container there can be any color that does not intersect with the header?

Answer (score 0):

Use Stack() with Positioned () widgets to achieve this.

Comment: behind the whole widget there may be a picture in the background therefore the color cannot be guessed there must be transparency

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```dart
 SizedBox(
        height: 150,
        width: 400,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: 150 - 48 / 2, // remove half title box height
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.amber, width: 5),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.grey[50],
                width: 150 / 2,
                height: 48,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                child: Text("title"),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text("1st item"),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ), // space between item
                  Text("second item item"),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

To learn more about [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Comment: behind the whole widget there may be a picture in the background
therefore the color cannot be guessed
there must be transparency

Comment: be sure about `may be a picture` and for that you can include another child at 1st on `Stack`